# MySQL SELECT Count many to many

Tags: mysql, sql, count, many-to-many

I have 3 tables (many to many relation)

- product (with "id" primary key)
- tags (with "id" primary key)
- product_tags (with product_id and tags_id as primary key)

I just want to create a SELECT COUNT query, so I can get the number of tags for each product. Even if the product doesn't have associated tag yet.

I've already used a query, but if there is no tags, the product doesn't display.

Do you have a solution please ?

**EDIT (my actual query)**

```
SELECT p.name, COUNT(pt.tags_id) as totalP
FROM tags t JOIN product p
LEFT JOIN product_tags pt 
  ON t.id = pt.tags_id 
     AND p.id = pt.product_id
```

**EDIT II**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fonction`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `product`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `fonction_product`;


CREATE TABLE `fonction` (
  `id` tinyint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ;

CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` tinyint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ref` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `col` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `point` tinyint(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `fonction_product` (
  `fonction_id` tinyint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `product_id` tinyint(6) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `fonction`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `fonction_product`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`fonction_id`,`product_id`),
  ADD KEY `product_id` (`product_id`);



INSERT INTO `fonction` (`id`, `name`, `reference`) VALUES (1, 'Contrôleur des accès', 'VLA56'), (2, 'Chauffeur', 'CMA6');


INSERT INTO `fonction_product` (`fonction_id`, `product_id`) VALUES (1, 1);


INSERT INTO `product` (`id`, `ref`, `name`, `description`, `col`, `image`, `point`) VALUES (1, '62475425', 'Pantalon 2 pinces pour Homme', 'Pantalon taille basse à revers pour homme', 'Rouge', '62475425.jpg', 50);
```

Comment: So why not post your (not completely correct) query? We would then probably say that you just have to use `left join` instead of `join` to include rows that have no tags.

Comment: @Solarflare it's done !

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.name, count(pt.tags_id) as total_tags
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_tags pt 
  ON p.id = pt.product_id
GROUP BY p.name
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but same problem... If the product has no tag (so no row in the product_tags table), it doesn't show up in the results

Comment: I dont think so, you should get 0 for product without tags, show us sample data and I will do a demo for you.

Comment: @Yoyo the best way to thank you on SO is to accept the answer ;)